#  Command to trim the first and last character of a line in a text file

Tags: sed

I am looking for I one liner hopefully, that can trim the first and last character of a line, on multiple lines e.g. test.txt

Before:

```
xyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyx
pyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz
```

After:

```
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ cat /tmp/txt
xyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyx
pyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz

$ sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' /tmp/txt
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

There is little trick :)

sed 's/^.(.*).$/\1/' file > file1 ; rm file ; echo file1 > file ; rm file1

Comment: Probably better to just use `sed -i file`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne 's,^.\(.*\).$,\1,p'
```

This command will delete all lines that have less than two characters, since one cannot really strip the first *and* last character from them.